# use scan() function in R to extract value from console

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to extract an integer value from R console by asking the user the question: "How many dice do you want to save?". The user can only choose a number between 1 to 5.
Following is my code snippet:

```
# .... previous steps to roll 5 dices and print output 
cat("Player ", player_start, ":\nDice after 1 roll(s):\n", x, "\nHow many dice do you want to save?")

number_saved_dices <- scan()

#if number_saved_dices out of the range, stop the function
if(number_saved_dices > 5 || number_saved_dices < 0 ) {
  stop("You can only save between 0 and 5 dices. Try again:")  
} else if(number_saved_dices == 5 ) {
  #if player wants to save all five 
  print("For which category should the result be used?")  
} else if( 0< number_saved_dices < 5 ) { 
  print("Please enter the values of the dice to save.") 
}
```

For example, if the user wants to save 12 dices, then the script should be stopped with the error message "You can only save between 0 and 5 dices. Try again. "  However, I can't perform if-else control flow with the number_saved_dices.

I would appreciate any help or insight!!

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: use `number_saved_dices<- as.integer(readline('How many dice do you want to save? '))`

Comment: thank you for the rapid reply! it indeed works with readline(), however I am trying to understand why it won't work with the scan() function

Comment: because `scan` is used to read files/text connections. And not prompt values